# Audio pausing when device locks or sleeps MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios5, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have developed an audio app which plays music tracks. Inside the info.plist file in MonoTouch, I have added the array property Required background modes with a value of audible content. The problem is that when the device's home button is pressed, the lock button is pressed or the device enters sleep mode by itself, the audio still stops playing and only resumes once the device is unlocked and the app is brought to the foreground again.

How can I keep the audio playing when one of these actions occur? The internet provides little information except for the info.plist solution for MonoTouch.

Comment: How do you play audio? SystemSound, AVFoundation.AVPlayer or 3rd-party libbary?

Comment: Hi Maxim, I use AVFoundation and the AudioToolbox. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

In order for that kind of app to play music when in the background or when the screen is locked, you have to set its Audio Session category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`:

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil; 

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

if (setCategoryError) {
    NSLog(@"couldn't setup audio session category!");
}
```

More about this in Apple's [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html).